# check/uncheck checkbox in Jquery

Tags: jquery

this is my .aspx page where i am using JQuery
Based on the check box checked and  uncheck i should make an div  display and  hide
i here when i am displaying the div tag i am even reseting the dropdown values

but when ever i check/uncheck the checkbox nothing seems happening

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <%-- <script type="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript.js"></script>--%>

    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
    if ($("#CheckBox1").is(':checked')) 
    { 
     $('#divControlGroup').css("display", "block"); 
     $("#ddlcounty option:first").attr("selected", true);

    } 
    else 
    { 
    $('#divControlGroup').css("display", "none"); 

     } 
    })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="false" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="divControlGroup" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcounty" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">India</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">US</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">UK</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

pls  let me know where i amgoing where, any help would be great

Thanks

**finally anser for the problem**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
     $('#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>').change(function() 
    {    
     if($(this).is(':checked')) 
     {       
      $("#divControlGroup").css("display", "block");   
      $("#ddlcounty option:first").attr("selected", true); 
      } 
     else 
        { 
    $("#divControlGroup").css("display", "none"); 
     } 
        })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: just fyi, you can use .show() and .hide(), which does the same thing as the css thing you have, just shorter.

Comment: And after looking at your code, you want to add a click event. You don't have one currently, so it's only going to run when the DOM is ready. I'm not going to post more code as there are plenty of posts on SO that cover this topic already. Just do a quick search or look on the right to related topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code only executes once when the page is loaded. It looks like you'll want to bind to the checkbox's `change` event:

```
$('#CheckBox1').change(function() {

   if($(this).is(':checked')) {

      ...

   }

});
```

**Update**

I just noticed you're using .NET controls. If the above code does not solve your problem, the issue is probably that the *rendered* IDs are not the same as the IDs you give your control. In your browser, select View Source, to see what the ID *really* is.

If you're using .NET 4, you can set `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your checkbox, to make sure that the ID of the rendered control will really be `CheckBox1`.

See [`ClientIDMode`](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/703_Understanding_ClientIDMode_Mode_Feature_in_ASP_net_4_0.aspx).

If you're using a .NET version lower than 4, you would have to pass `CheckBox1.ClientID` to your JavaScript.

Something like:

```
$('#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>').change(function() {

   if($(this).is(':checked')) {

      ...

   }

});
```

Another option, which will work regardless of .NET version, would be to assign an ID to a wrapper:

```
<td id="my-checkbox">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="false" />
</td>

$('#my-checkbox :checkbox').change(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Hi david, pls see  my code  still same  issues  continues  let me knw is thera any wrong here?

Comment: @happy: The code you've included in your question does not contain a change event listener, as the ones described in my and Bogdan's answer, and alluded to in seth's answer and Matt's comment. You will need to add such a listener. The code I've provided should work.

Comment: pls see  my code   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {

    $('#CheckBox1').change(function() 
    {    
     if($(this).is(':checked')) 
     {       
      $("#divControlGroup").css("display", "block");    
      } 
     else 
        { 
    $("#divControlGroup").css("display", "none"); 
     } 
        })
        });
    </script>

Comment: @happy: The code you've pasted in your comment works, provided that your markup is right. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/jUEmy/). However, that got me thinking that your markup might not be what you think it is. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks david it works fine now here is my code                            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
     $('#<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>').change(function() 
    {    
     if($(this).is(':checked')) 
     {       
      $("#divControlGroup").css("display", "block");   
      $("#ddlcounty option:first").attr("selected", true); 
      } 
     else 
        { 
    $("#divControlGroup").css("display", "none"); 
     } 
        })
        });
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not attached to the checkbox's change event, it is only executing on "ready" which means that it's only executed one time, when the page is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. I'm assuming this is what you want.

```
$('#CheckBox1').change(function () {
   $('#divControlGroup').toggle('slow');
});
```